# Android : Webrtc How to record the both audio of (sender and receiver) while recording the video call

Tags: android, webrtc, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, webrtc-android

As I tried to record the video call using `webrtc` library. Either i can record the initiator call audio or the receiver end audio.

```
public static void startRecordingToFile(String filePath, Integer id, @Nullable VideoTrack videoTrack, @Nullable AudioChannel audioChannel, EglBase eglBase, PeerConnectionConfClient peerConnectionClient, AudioSamplesInterceptor inputSamplesInterceptor) throws Exception {

    AudioSamplesInterceptor interceptor = null;
    if (audioChannel == AudioChannel.INPUT)
        interceptor = inputSamplesInterceptor;
    else if (audioChannel == AudioChannel.OUTPUT) {

        if (outputSamplesInterceptor == null)
            outputSamplesInterceptor = new OutputAudioSamplesInterceptor(peerConnectionClient.getJavaAudioDeviceModule());
        interceptor = outputSamplesInterceptor;
    }
    MediaRecorderImpl mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorderImpl(id, videoTrack, interceptor, eglBase);
    File file = new File(filePath);
    mediaRecorder.startRecording(file);
    mediaRecorders.append(id, mediaRecorder);
}
```

In the above code, i can either record the `AudioChannel.INPUT` or `AudioChannel.OUTPUT`. But I would like to merge the both `Input` and `Output` audio in a video call using webrtc library.

Please help us out with your suggestions.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/65338544/918910.